# Why is a closed session still usable?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Why is the session still available after closing? How can I close it correctly?

```
@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        raise e
    finally:
        session.close()
        print('finally close session')

with session_scope() as session:
    query = session.query(Image)

# Before that, it has been output finally close session
a = query.filter(Image.id == 1).first()   # why can run 
print(a.id)
b = Image()
query.session.add(b)   # why can run
query.session.flush()
print(b.id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour: closing a session does not make it unusable.  From the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#closing):

> The Session.close() method issues a Session.expunge_all() which removes all ORM-mapped objects from the session, and releases any transactional/connection resources from the Engine object(s) to which it is bound. When connections are returned to the connection pool, transactional state is rolled back as well.

> When the Session is closed, it is essentially in the original state as when it was first constructed, and may be used again. In this sense, the Session.close() method is more like a “reset” back to the clean state and not as much like a “database close” method.

Comment: Thank you. What will happen if I don't execute the shutdown

Comment: If you don't close the session you risk exhausting the connection pool (because new sessions will checkout connections but not return them to the pool).

Comment: a = query.filter(Image.id == 1).first() How should I close a like this

Comment: query.session.close()?

Comment: In standard SQLAlchemy, `query` is an attribute of a session, so you close the session once you have finished with it.  If you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy, sessions are managed automatically: there is no need to manually create or close them.

Comment: I use fastapi,flask-sqlalchemy how to close the session automatically,and very thanks !

Comment: For fastapi, use the sessionlocal/get_db dependency injection pattern as show [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-a-dependency)